# An Error Occured During Local report Processing

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I'm trying to do auto print on printer but the error `"An Error Occured during Local report Processing"` occurs. This is my code:

```
private Stream CreateStream(string name,
              string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding,
              string mimeType, bool willSeek)
                {
                Stream stream = new FileStream(@"..\..\" + name +
                   "." + fileNameExtension, FileMode.Create);
                m_streams.Add(stream);
                return stream;
                }
            // Export the given report as an EMF (Enhanced Metafile) file.
            private void Export(LocalReport report)
                {
                string deviceInfo =
                  "<DeviceInfo>" +
                  "  <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>" +
                  "  <PageWidth>2.5in</PageWidth>" +
                  "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
                  "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
                  "  <MarginLeft>2in</MarginLeft>" +
                  "  <MarginRight>5in</MarginRight>" +
                  "  <MarginBottom>0in</MarginBottom>" +
                  "</DeviceInfo>";
                Warning[] warnings;
                m_streams = new List<Stream>();
                report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
                   out warnings);
                foreach(Stream stream in m_streams)
                    stream.Position = 0;
                }
            // Handler for PrintPageEvents
            private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
                {
                Metafile pageImage = new
                   Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);
                ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, ev.PageBounds);
                m_currentPageIndex++;
                ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
                }

            private void Print()
                {
                const string printerName =
                   "HP LaserJet 2300 PCL6 Class Driver";
                if(m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
                    return;
                PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
                printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
                if(!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
                    {
                    string msg = String.Format(
                       "Can't find printer \"{0}\".", printerName);
                    MessageBox.Show(msg, "Print Error");
                    return;
                    }
                printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
                printDoc.Print();
                }

    Code Button Click Event

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    ds.WriteXmlSchema("sample.xml");
    ds.ReadXml("sample.xml");
    ds.WriteXmlSchema("sample.xsd");

    LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
    report.ReportPath = "SaleReport1.rdlc";
    report.DataSources.Add(
    new ReportDataSource("Table1", ds.Tables[0]));
    Export(report);
    m_currentPageIndex = 0;
    Print();
```

Comment: are you using windows authentication ? or SQL authentication ?

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [An error occurred during report processing. RLDC reporting in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966954/an-error-occurred-during-report-processing-rldc-reporting-in-asp-net-mvc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is not a problem of the code you posted but an error in your report definition.

You have to catch the Exception and give a look at the various levels of InnerException; i.e.:

```
ex.Message
ex.InnerException.Message
ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue . An error occurred during report processing. DatasetName and I found an issue with the connection string; I had to switch from using windows authentication to sql authentication, then my report worked.

the Report Data Source Name must match with the Name you are providing through the ReportDataSource object

Comment: no m not working with sql bro m using xml dataset fill from xml and xml fill from datatable and i was creating datatable column dynimically and give him the values